# RGoogleDocs and now RGoogleData

Tags: r, google-docs

[RGoogleDocs](http://www.omegahat.org/RGoogleDocs/) is fantastic. It allows one to store data on Google and read it in in real time to R. I tried to install it on a computer the other day and lo and behold all I could find was RGoogleData in RForge. What is the relationship between the two packages? I tried to google search RGoogleData and RGoogleDocs in the same search and found nothing. Duncan Temple Lang wrote RGoogleDocs and it appears that Adrian A. Dragulescu wrote RGoogleData.

I could have sworn that a windows binary of RGoogleDocs had been posted in omegahat by Duncan Temple Lang but alas in the past couple of months I no longer see omegahat on the select repository option list from RGUI. Instead RForge is now on that list. What is the relationship between omegahat and RForge?

Comment: By the way, I just found an e-mail correspondence from Duncan Temple Lang from July in which he advised me
 install.packages("RGoogleDocs", repos = "http://www.omegahat.org/R")

Comment: I have used RGoogleData quite a lot in the past few days. It works. For some reason RGoogleDocs has become "broken" in the past few days. I do not know why but it is not able to read from wisely, the spreadsheet side of Google Docs.

RGoogleDocs seems to rely on RCurl to get into the google data and to read it. RGoogleData seems to rely on rJava to do that. I do not understand the difference in the techniques but I have noticed that RGoogleData reads very very very slowly compared to RGoogleDocs but at least it is not currently broken - for me at least.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

RGoogleDocs is on omegahat: http://www.omegahat.org/RGoogleDocs/
RGoogleData is on RForge: http://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/rgoogledata/

RForge is a sourceforge-like place for the development of R packages.
Omegahat is more general, providing open-source software for statistical applications. That includes some R packages, but also software for other environments.

R packages on both sites can be installed directly using `install.packages()` with the appropriate repos setting.

Comment: I'd add that R-Forge is used by hundreds of developers whereas Omegahat is effectively just Duncan TL.

Comment: @Dirk: Its just Duncan? **Wow**, he is prolific.