# Downloading RGoogleDocs for R (it fails)

Tags: r, download, package, google-docs

I am trying:

```
install.packages("RGoogleDocs", repos = "http://www.omegahat.org/R")
```

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794318/rgoogledocs-and-now-rgoogledata), but it doesn't work.

I ended up manually downloading the file from [here](http://www.omegahat.org/R/bin/windows/contrib/R-2.9/).

What other ways are there for me to get to the file directly?

Thanks,
Tal

Comment: What is your R version? Your manual link is to 2.9 version, in 2.10 version directory is missing RGoogleDocs.

Comment: likewise for RGoogleTrands and the RNYTimes (same repository)--i haven't been able to successfully install either since v. 2.10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Marek says, there doesn't appear to be a version for R 2.10: http://www.omegahat.org/R/bin/windows/contrib/2.10/.  This command works for me in R 2.9, but not in R 2.10:

```
install.packages("RGoogleDocs", repos = "http://www.omegahat.org/R", type="source")
```