# Work around in RGoogleDocs with two-step verification?

Tags: r, google-api

I try to use `RGoogleDocs` and get

> Error: Forbidden

I have two-step verification on: is there a work-around?

```
sheets.con = getGoogleDocsConnection(getGoogleAuth(user, ps, service = "wise"))
```

> Error: Forbidden

[Relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794318/rgoogledocs-and-now-rgoogledata/30917820#30917820)

Comment: have you tried turning two-step verification off for the purposes of testing whether you can otherwise successfully connect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getGoogleAuth` of RGoogleDocs package is based on an officially deprecated ClientLogin to connect google server, see https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/AuthForInstalledApps?csw=1

You may use the application password of google as a try.

Another way is just use the url of you google docs to visit certain contents, see http://www.r-bloggers.com/access-google-spreadsheet-directly-in-bash-and-in-r/

Update：

In the source code of `getGoogleAuth`, the author used an application called 'R-GoogleDocs-0.1', you may apply an new application and get the token. Then I think you could use the token and the api from google to access google docs directly in R. However, such hacks almost mean update/rewrite RGoogleDocs package.